# Generating a comma delimited string, from select element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what's going on. I have a select element, for which I need to get a comma delimited string of all its options, regardless of whether or not it's selected.

How can I, in jQuery/javascript take this:

```
    <select id="currentTags" multiple>
        <option>Nature</option>
        <option>Cats</option>
        <option>Space</option>
    </select>
```

and turn it into this:

```
    "Nature, Cats, Space"
```

I tried to find ways of doing this and couldn't... I'm still learning javascript, and my limited knowledge is stopping me in my tracks.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just to guide me in the right direction.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
var result = $('#currentTags option').map(function(i, opt) {
  return $(opt).text();
}).toArray().join(', ');
```

In plain JavaScript you can do something similar like this:

```
// Convert pseudo-arrays to real arrays
var __slice = Array.prototype.slice;

// Get select options as real array
var opts = __slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#currentTags option'));

// Map the text of each option
var result = opts.map(function(x) {
  return x.textContent;
}).join(', ');

console.log(result); //=> "Nature, Cats, Space"
```

The advantage of abstracting elements into collections instead of looping is that you maintain a consistent API (like jQuery), and you don't need to create extra variables to loop pseudo-arrays, as real arrays can use all array methods.

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) to learn more about the DOM and the methods  and properties you can use, like `querySelectorAll`, `children`, `textContent` and more.

**Edit:** This should work in IE9+ and all modern browsers.

Comment: This is incredibly complex for a newcomer without explanation of what each section done. I'd recommend offering more explanation of each line

Comment: Also not a good idea to treat host objects like native, it will fail in various versions of IE at least.

Comment: I added some comments and a jQuery version. Not sure how to make it easier without diving into what pseudo-arrays and mapping is, and that would be a whole different question.

Comment: @RobG: This works today, in modern browsers, IE9+ AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! works well - even though I'm only understanding parts of it. I will be looking into all this to familiarize myself, and also the documentation you've linked. Thanks again!

Comment: @elclanrs what is the upshot to using map, instead of going through a loop and appending values as others have suggested?

Comment: Yeah, was testing in compat mode: :-(

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```
// Initialize your string
var output_string = "";

// For each 'option' tag, append its value to the string with the comma
$('#currentTags option').each(function() {
    output_string = output_string+this.text;
});

// Removing the last ', ' which were added during the loop
output_string = output_string.substr(0, output_string.length-2);
```

[Here's a Fiddle to see it into action :)](http://jsfiddle.net/Littm/FjSJs/3/)

Comment: @RobG: Sorry about that :P, I took your modification into account.

Comment: Nearly… now `$(this).text()` need to be just `this.text`. ;-) Direct property access will always be much faster (and less to write) that calling functions to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The plain old javascript (POJS) way is to get the select's options collection, then loop over it to get the values and generate a string with the required format, e.g.

```
var options = document.getElementById('currentTags').options;
var values = [];

for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  values.push(options[i].text);
}

alert(values.join(','));
```

You can write that in much more concise form but performance may suffer and depending on features used, may fail in some browsers. The above puts a premium on clarity and maintainability of code, performance will be at least as fast as any alternative.

Comment: I must admit, I do understand your version better than I do @elclanrs right now, which is a plus. I would like to know what you mean by "may fail" in some browsers.

Comment: elclanrs' solution passes a host object (the *NodeList* returned by *querySelctorAll*) to a native javascript method (*Array.prototype.slice*) as *this*. While the *slice* method is generic, host objects are not required to behave like native objects in this circumstance, therefore it should not be relied upon. In browsers like IE 8 and lower, this scenario is known to fail. The approach above is consistent with W3C DOM specifictions, ECAM-262, various published browser documents and browsers in use and therefore has an extremely low chance of failure in that regard.

Comment: Ah, ok - thank you for the clarification. We're only worrying about browsers from three generations ago though. Although I know some people are still using older versions - this particular site I'm building is a hobby site of mine, so that's not a worry for me. Although it's valuable information for any site I might make in the future so thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand. You have the choice of 5 lines of code that will only work in "modern browsers" (it will fail in IE 8 for more than 1 reason, which is in the range of "three generatsion ago"), or 5 lines of code that will work in every browser back to IE 5.5 (replace push with direct assignment and you get back to IE 4) and equivalent. I don't care which answer you accept, but do it with eyes open.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
var tags = [];
$('#currentTags option').each(function() {
    tags.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(tags.join(', ')); // 'Nature, Cats, Space'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wN2Dk/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple jQuery example:

```
var arr = []; // create array

$('#currentTags').children().each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).text()); // add option text to array
});

alert(arr.join(', ')); // Nature, Cats, Space
```

If you want the option `value`, switch `text()` to `val()` ;)